# TTL Gates Footprint changed

Tags: multisim

I have recently got Multisim 13.0 and I see some changes on it. It doesn't have the traditional footprints for AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR etc. Why?

When I add 7400N on the design, it has this icon:

[image]

I should get this instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHgWun.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am a beginner, and obviously a student, so I might have taken things wrong! Please explain me what is happening and how can I restore the standard footprints?

Comment: 7400 is a NAND, not an AND! The Multisim symbol is correct. They are not footprints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How Do I Change the Symbol Standard (DIN, ANSI) for an Entire Circuit in Multisim?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/8C3946143871D936862571F00055BAB7)

**Problem:** 
When I am loading a circuit file, the symbols are all in ANSI standard.  How do I change it to DIN standard?

**Solution:** 
The setting Options»Global Preferences»Components»Symbol Standard only effects newly placed components. To apply this setting to previously-placed components, you must update the symbols.

- Open the circuit containing ANSI instead of DIN symbols.
  Set Options»Global Preferences»Components»Symbol Standard to DIN
- Click OK
- Tools»Update components on sheet...
- Set the checkmark next to the Symbol column header to select all symbols to be updated.
  Unselect the checkmark next to the Model and Footprint columns header to leave these settings as they are.
- Click Update

Comment: It would help if you edited in the most relevant bits in case the link ever goes stale.